# How get the value from a Object of class through a String?

Tags: java, string

I have this class

```
public class Register{
   String name;
   int value;
   int lockedValue = 0;

   Registro(String name){  this.name = name; }

   public int getValue(){ return value; }
   // rest of get and set methods
}
```

and the main class

```
public class Simulator{

   static Register $t0, $t1, $t2;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      $t1 = new Register("$t1");
      $t1.setValue(15);
      $t2 = new Register("$t2");
      $t2.setValue(20);


     // here i can get values by $t1.getValue()
   }   

}
```

I can get the value with a `String`?, like as:

```
String nameRegister = "$t1";
int fetchValue = nameRegister.getValue();
```

Comment: You could use a `Map<String, Register>`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you don't make that an answer, I won't upvote it.

Comment: Hint: you **never** use the $ character in variable names. $ is (by convention) for *generated* code only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to "identify" objects by some string based name. If so, the appropriate data structure in Java is a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). In your case, you would need something like:

```
Map<String, Integer> registry = new HashMap<>();
registry.put("t1", 15);
registry.put("t2", 20);
```

And later you can query this using

```
Integer value = registry.get("t1");
```

If you want to store "arbitrary" values, you can/have to use a `Map<String, ? extends Object>` though. But that isn't exactly a good approach in the first place; as you loose all the compile-time checking that generics would give you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you may modify the `getValue` method in the following way:

```
  public <T> T getValue(Function<Integer, T> parser) {
      return Optional.of(value).map(parser).get();
  }
```

Example:

```
  Register $t2 = new Register("$t2");
  $t2.setValue(20);

  //getting values

  Long longValue = $t2.getValue(Integer::longValue);
  Double doubleValue = $t2.getValue(Integer::doubleValue);
  String stringValue = $t2.getValue(i -> i.toString());
  Integer integerValue = $t2.getValue(Integer::valueOf);
  System.out.print("long: " + longValue + ", double: " + doubleValue + ", string: " + stringValue + ", integer: " + integerValue);
```

Output:
`long: 20, double: 20.0, string: 20, integer: 20`

Comment: Just for the record: I think the OP is a real java newbie. Do you really think he is able to figure what your answer has to do with his question? Me, I doubt that.

Comment: I'm _not_ a Java newbie and I can't figure out what this answer has to do with the question.